# Alexa won't turn on/off my lamp anymore

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, smart-lights, smart-assistants

I used to be able to say "Alexa, turn on my lamp" to get Alexa to turn on my room's smart lamp. However, sometime last week, this command stopped working. Now, when I try it, Alexa says "My Tile doesn't support that". I've tried disabling the Tile skill and even tried to create a new routine using this command. However, Alexa still won't turn on my lamp through this command. Has anyone else experienced this issue? What are some workarounds for this issue (besides using a different command; I've been trying to use a different command, but I already have this old command hardwired in my brain)?

Comment: So what does Alexa respond with now? What kind of lamp is it? Can you still control the lamp through its app? Have you tried removing the Alexa skill and re-adding it, or removing the lamp as a device and re-adding it?

Comment: `I've been trying to use a different command` ... did that work?

Comment: @romkey As I said in my post, Alexa now responds by saying "My Tile doesn't support that", even after I disabled the Tile skill. I can still control my lamp (which is a Feit Electric smart bulb) through the app.

Comment: @jsotola At first, this workaround didn't work. But yesterday, it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

When this issue first came up, I created an Alexa routine as a workaround. This routine would use the trigger "Alexa, turn on my lamp", like before. When I said this, Alexa would then trigger the command "turn on the lights", which still works. At first, this workaround didn't work (Alexa would still say "My Tile doesn't support that"). However, starting yesterday, this workaround began to work. I guess it just needed some time to start working.